# How to transfer data from JSP to servlet to java bean

Tags: jsp, servlets

I know we can get a single piece of data using request.getParameter("name"). 
such as:
   String name = request.getParameter("name");

But what if there 100 parameters? Is there a simple way to transfer all input data in a jsp, to a java bean in a servlet by one line?

All information would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do your property names match your request parameter names? If they do, then you can use <jsp:setProperty name="mybean" property="*" />

Comment: I am not sure what exactly do you want, but maybe `request.getParameterMap()` that returns `Map<String, String[]>` will help you.

Comment: Yes, <jsp:setProperty..> will do. But that is in another jsp, not servlet?

Comment: Yes, that tag must be used in a JSP.  From that JSP, you can forward to your Servlet.